# select with cross apply doesn't return the intended result

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select
    *
from
    (select level l from dual connect by level <4) t cross apply
    (select tt.a from (
        select level a from dual connect by level < t.l ) tt )
```

return

```
L A
1 1
2 1
3 1
```

But I have expected

```
L A
2 1
3 1
3 2
```

because

```
select level a from dual connect by level < 1 -> Null
select level a from dual connect by level < 2 -> 1
select level a from dual connect by level < 3 -> 1,2
```

Comment: I get four rows when I run this code:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f1de326da4d835ee51bd3f4f8fdb6306.

Answer (score 2):

Your question reflects a very common misunderstanding of hierarchical queries. Namely:

The `connect by` condition only applies to levels 2 and above. If there is no `start with` clause, level 1 will **always** be generated. Conditions on level 1 are given in the `start with` clause, not in `connect by`.

To get your desired result, you must add a `start with` clause, with the same condition (namely, `level < t.l`).

However, **testing** the modified query results in an error; that is caused by correlation more than one level deep, which is really a problem related to `cross apply`, not to the hierarchical bit.

**EDIT** - Actually it seems that using `level` in the `start with` clause doesn't work as expected either. I am leaving this answer up, though - the explanation of why your expectation was incorrect is still valid.

Comment: Interesting. This [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6e67d2429ed63a5377b827c029ffa717) shows that `start with` "sees" starting level as `0`, so your solution will work if we use `start with level + 1 < t.l`. Or `where` clause.